# comma in function arguments causes strange argument split in codeblocks

Tags: c++, c++14, codeblocks

I'm trying to write a function that can take vectors containing int arrays with a length of 3 as an argument. After a bit of reading I was instructed to do this by putting a std::array into a std::vector. However I cannot seem to figure out how to do this.

Here's my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

void example(int unrelated_argument1, std::vector<std::array<int, 3> > argument, int unrelated_argument);

void example(int unrelated_argument1, std::vector<std::array<int, 3> > argument, int unrelated_argument)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < argument.size(); i++)
    {
        printf("Contents of array number %i are %i %i %i\n", i, argument[i][0],argument[i][1], argument[i][2]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::array <int, 3> >test_vector;

    std::array<int, 3> test_array1 = {1, 2, 3};
    std::array<int, 3> test_array2 = {10, 20, 30};
    std::array<int, 3> test_array3 = {1000, 2000, 3000};

    test_vector.push_back(test_array1);
    test_vector.push_back(test_array2);
    test_vector.push_back(test_array3);

    example(0, test_vector, 0);
}
```

I expected the function called `example` to take 3 arguments here, however my IDE(codeblocks) claims that this results in 4 arguments:

Those being `int unrelated_argument1`, `std::vector<std::array<int`, `3> > argument`and `int unrelated_argument2`.

The second and third arguments here are incorrect: I expected the argument to be `std::vector<std::array<int, 3> > argument` instead.

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Edit: After a whole bit more reading and research, it seems that this is a known bug in codeblocks. https://sourceforge.net/p/codeblocks/tickets/491/ The code here appears to be correct.

Comment: It should work. Please make an [mcve] and add the exact error message.

Comment: Is this a compiler error or an indexing error of your IDE? It is 3 arguments but perhaps it just your IDE that is confused?

Comment: The code you posted is missing either a semicolon `;` at the end, or a function body in curly braces `{}`.

Comment: `void example(int unrelated_argument, std::vector<std::array<int, 4>> argument, int unrelated_argument2) {}` compiles just fine on VS2015.  Notice the trailing `{}`, like @Galik said.

Comment: I have added some basic example code that causes the error.

Comment: @parrotsssssss Cannot reproduce: https://wandbox.org/permlink/INkhETFzEkW3sUHQ. What version of Codeblocks do you use? It seems to be unaware of templates. Is your project targeting C++ language?

Comment: There's no error message. The problem is the unexpected behavior in codeblocks that claims that this function has the 4 arguments above instead of the expected 3. Should I assume that this is an IDE problem instead of a code one or is my code formatted in an unusual way that might cause IDEs to incorrectly interpret it? I'm using version 17.12.

Comment: @parrotsssssss Your code is fine as far as I can tell. It compiles with both GCC, Clang, and MSVC as well: https://rextester.com/YHECJI81875. Either it is a IDE bug or some wrong setup of your project. Is it a C++ project (not C)?

Comment: Yes, it is a C++ project. Here is a screenshot of the issue in the IDE if it helps: https://i.imgur.com/gFQYWEM.png

Comment: If the code compiles and works, but the IDE claims it's wrong. Most likely your IDE is wrong.

Comment: @parrotsssssss I just downloaded Code::Blocks 17.12, created a C++ console project, pasted your code and everything works just fine.

Comment: @DanielLangr Thanks for the effort, perhaps my installation is wrong then; I've also created a C++ console project and pasted the code again however when attempting to type out the function the issue of codeblocks recognizing 4 arguments instead of 3 remained.

Comment: @parrotsssssss Then, I would suggest you to ask about this issue on the Code::Blocks Forum: http://forums.codeblocks.org/.

Comment: First you said ***"There's no error message."*** and then you said ***"...codeblocks that claims that this function has the 4 arguments above instead of the expected 3"***. How can both be true? In what way does anything "claims that this function has the 4 arguments above instead of the expected 3". Can you give the exact wording?

Comment: @Galik Codeblocks has a feature that will tell you what arguments a function has as you're typing it out and will highlight the current argument. In the screenshot of the issue I provided earlier(https://i.imgur.com/gFQYWEM.png) codeblocks is supposed to highlight the third argument in blue. However, as it can be seen, it separates the real second argument into 2 different ones(because of the comma I assume) for a total of 4 and highlights the third incomplete one. `std::vector<std::array<int` and `3>>argument` are supposed to be just a single argument.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research it appears that this is indeed a bug in codeblocks and not the above code. https://sourceforge.net/p/codeblocks/tickets/491/ As of this post, the latest stable version(17.12) still has this bug. If you also encounter this bug you probably want to try one of the nightly builds instead.